How to get 7 days temperature graph in HP ILO4?
I'm a bit new to System administration.
I have few HP servers with ILO3 and ILO4 running.
I can check the current temperatures in ILO but i want to see last 7 days server temperatures.
Its very easy in Dell IDRAC but in HP i couldnt find any way to do this.
Also tried PRTG and Checkmk but these software also just show current temperatures.
Please guide
